# Free/Open Source Flash Builders?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Hey guys! I'm just a student who's looking into building about 1 or 2 flash files that would need both the movie-making and actionscripting capabilities of Adobe Flash Professional. Problem is it costs $120, and that's a huge burden to me!

I've did some research and found a few free or open source programs, but they are either:

a) For making animations ONLY

b) For writing Actionscript 3 ONLY

So here's my questions:

1) Is there any way I can make a flash movie using a program from a), and then inserting AS3 into it using a program from b)?

2) Or are there any free programs that are similar to Adobe Flash Professional?

THANKS!

Comment: Have you tried the free trial of Flash Pro? I think it's 30 or 60 days..

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is as good as it gets:

http://www.sapphiresteel.com/Adobe-Flex-Development-in-Visual

They have a free version and a paid version. The paid version is several hundred dollars less than flash professional or flash builder. There are plenty of other tools out there but other than this, no real feature-complete IDE that supports both visual design and coding. Well, there is the design view plugin for flashdevelop, but it's buggy at best:

http://designview.sourceforge.net/#

(Search Flex Design View)
http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=3rd_Party_Plugins
http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?t=2934
http://www.steamed-design.com/2009/07/free-flex-ide.html

And that is pretty much what you're lookin at. There may be some stuff of interest in these posts, but no real solution:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_for_Linux

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974078/alternatives-of-flex-builder

Comment: Is it possible for me to create a swf movie using kToon, and then inserting actionscript into it using one of the programs you mentioned?

Comment: I dont believe so, but I'm not one to say something is impossible. What I'll say instead is that if you could do it, it would probably be extremely tedious and difficult.